# Dynamic validating - just one append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to quick validate it and shows it in pop-up **#result**, but
I can't add my item only once. I tried **e.preventDefault();** and **e.stopPropagation();** - both didn't work. **.html** isn't a solution, because I wan't two (or more) paragraphs in a div. How to stop'em?

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/9n2db67u/1/)

My html code:

HTML:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post">
<span> Write pwd: </span> 
<input id="login" name="login" type="text" />
</form>
<div id="result" class="tooltip"></div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#login').keyup(function() {
    var th = document.getElementById('login').value;
        if (th.length < 6){
            $('#result').css('display','inline');
            $('#result').append('<p id="too_short">Too short password.</p>');
        }   else{
        $("#too_short").remove();
        }

        if (th.contains('\'') || th.contains('\"') || th.contains('\\') || th.contains('\/')){
            $('#result').css('display','inline');
            $('#result').append('<p id="forb_char">Forbidden characters</p>');
        }   else{
            $("#forb_char").remove();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if i got your question, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qwux7o9r/1/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Valerio Isn't this going to throw a error when trying to remove warnings if they don't exist yet?

Comment: @nicael you're right, I think it would be better to have all the empty divs in the static html and then fill them and empty them using html() and empty() methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, try it http://jsfiddle.net/amostk/9n2db67u/17/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#login').keyup(function() {
var th = document.getElementById('login').value;
    if (th.length < 6){
        $('#result').css('display','inline');
//add a variable to check if #too_sort exist
        var ex = $("#too_short").text();
//if it exists, do not append again else add
        if(!ex)
        {
            $('#result').append('<p id="too_short">Too short password.</p>');
//remove #forb_char if exists
            $("#forb_char").remove();
        }
    }   else{
      $("#too_short").remove();
    }

    if (th.contains('\'') || th.contains('\"') || th.contains('\\') || th.contains('\/')){
        $('#result').css('display','inline');
   //add a varible to check if "#forb_char exists

       var en = $("#forb_char").text();
   // if exists do not add else add
        if(!en)
        {
        $('#result').append('<p id="forb_char">Forbidden characters</p>');
 //remove all #too_short for only one validation
            $("#too_short").remove();
        }
    }   else{
        $("#forb_char").remove();
    }

});
});
```

Comment: Thank You, that's perfect, I've just commented out inner elses.

Answer (score 1):

- Well, it is not so clear what you need in your question but this is what I did from what I've understood.
- I implemented this a little bit cleaner and fixed the behavior *(I hope it's what you need)*.
- Just to add something. If you need more complex validations in future or reduce lines of code try the following plugin which is really helpful and easy to use: http://jqueryvalidation.org/
- ***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/nwu3ojft/

---

***HTML:***

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="POST"> 
    <span>Write pwd: </span> 
    <input id="login" name="login" type="text" />
</form>
<div id="result" class="tooltip"></div>
```

***CSS:***

Specify the `display` property needed from first time, no need to add it each time when validating your password.

```
div.#result {
    display: inline;
}
```

***jQuery:***

Please read code comments.

```
// Available error messages
var errorMessage = {
    tooShort: 'Too short password', 
    forbChar: 'Forbidden characters'
};

$(function() {

    var login = $('#login');

    login.on('keyup', function(e) {
        var pwd = this.value, 
            isValid = isValidPwd(pwd, true);

        if (isValid) {
            // Clear error message
            setMsg('');
        }
    });

});

/**
 * Check if password input is valid
 *
 * @param {String} value To be checked
 * @param {Boolean} showErrors Flag to display errors or not
 * @returns {Boolean} isValid
 */
function isValidPwd(value, showErrors) {
    var isValid = true, 
        error;

    // Rule #1
    if (value && value.length < 6) {
        error = '<p>' + errorMessage.tooShort + '</p>';
        isValid = false;
    } 

    // Rule #2
    if (value && (value.indexOf('\'') >= 0 || 
               value.indexOf('\"') >= 0 || 
               value.indexOf('\\') >= 0 || 
               value.indexOf('\/') >= 0)) {
        error = '<p>' + errorMessage.forbChar + '</p>';
        isValid = false;
    }

    // Check flag
    if (showErrors) {
        setMsg(error);
    }

    return isValid;
};

/**
 * Used to set a message in the UI
 */
function setMsg(value) {
    $('#result').html(value);
};
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I need that to show both messages at the one time or even more, but It's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have already added your warning using `indexOf()`:

```
if($('#result').text().indexOf("Too short password.")==-1){
     if (th.length < 6){
        $('#result').css('display','inline');
        $('#result').append('<p id="too_short">Too short password.</p>');
    }
}else{
    $("#too_short").remove();
}

if($('#result').text().indexOf("Forbidden characters")==-1){
   if (th.contains('\'') || th.contains('\"') || th.contains('\\') || th.contains('\/')){
        $('#result').css('display','inline');
        $('#result').append('<p id="forb_char">Forbidden characters</p>');
    }
}else{
    $("#forb_char").remove();
}
```

Comment: Inner if/else will be used only once, because we check that if some text exists. If not exists, do some work, else nothing. We can move out else, but thank You for an answer.